# Spim MIPS Simulator not launching (Stanford cs143)

Tags: compiler-construction, spim

Currently trying to do assignments for Stanford's cs143 class. ([edx online course](https://www.edx.org/learn/computer-science/stanford-university-compilers))

When I try to run spim, I get this error:

[image]

The file directory shows that that file does in fact exist. I also don't know what the "unary operator expected" error is coming from.

The directory has been added to PATH, all aliases all correct, etc. I am SSH'd into a ubuntu server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.